# find the different string from file comparison in unix

Tags: diff

I have 2 files:

- `File1`:

  ```
  DX 100860599215|732512737|00002|40|1|20220105|20220105|20220523|31014280|5892720|36907000|1|20220105|40|20|D|
  ```
- `File2`

  ```
  DX 100860599216|732512737|00002|40|1|20220105|20220105|20220523|31014280|5892720|36907000|1|20220105|40|20|D|
  ```

I want to get only the differing string from this and not full line

```
100860599215
100860599216
```

any help here pls

Answer (score 1):

I came with this ugly solution

```
diff <(tr  '|'  \\n < file1 ) <(tr  '|' \\n < file2)
```

giving

```
1c1
< DX 100860599215
---
> DX 100860599216
```

where

- `tr '|' \\n < file1` flatten file each `'|'` is turn to a new line
- `<(   )` construct make a pseudo file from inside command

---

as per comment, replacing `tr  '|'  \\n < file1` by `tr  ' |'  '\n\n' < file1` give a result closer to expected result.

```
diff <(tr  ' |'  '\n\n' < file1 ) <(tr  ' |' '\n\n' < file2)
2c2
< 100860599215
---
> 100860599216
```

Comment: If you use `tr ' |' '\n\n'` you split the initial `DX` off too, which will give you something that looks more like what the user wants.

Comment: @Archemar, if OP literally wants exactly what he stated '100860599215' and '100860599216' (without 'DX' and 'space' between them), we can do this with awk and/or sed/cut: `diff <(tr  '|'  \\n < file1 ) <(tr  '|' \\n < file2) | awk 'NF==3 {print $3}'`. Of course if pattern with 'DX' 'space' and 'string' is allways the same...